# How to load .mat file in matlab workspace

Tags: matlab

I have a .mat file where three different voltage signal data are given. when i am using the command  load name.mat in command it is showing "Error using load
Unable to read file 'name.mat': no such file or directory." Do i have to place that file in particular folder so that matlab can find?

I have another question how to generate voltage signal from from that file as in that file only values are given.. i have to plot the signal .. so i have to build the signal from the graph...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely that name1.mat is not in your search path.

MATLAB uses the idea of a search path to determine where it searches for files and functions. Basically, MATLAB can only find files if they are in your path. Your current working directory is automatically included in MATLAB's search path. To view your path, use the function `path`. You can use the command `pwd` to print your working directory, `cd` to change directory, and `ls` to list the contents of the working directory. You can also perform all these operations through the GUI.

See [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html) and the help documentation of the above functions for the full details.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cd` to change the current working directory to the folder where `name.mat` is located.